# Find the Value of $\sin^2A + \sin^2B + \sin^2C$ given the following data.

Tags: trigonometry, summation

If $2\tan^2A\tan^2B\tan^2C + \tan^2A\tan^2B + \tan^2B\tan^2C + \tan^2C\tan^2A = 1$, then find the value of $\sin^2A + \sin^2B + \sin^2C$.

My attempt

1). I tried to multiply both sides by $\cos^2A\cos^2B\cos^2C$ in given. Then took common but after that, I didn't get what to do next

2). I tried to relate the given with $(ab+bc+ca)^2,$ but it also didn't work... 
I could only think of these two ways but nothing worked for me...

Comment: It is customary to put a description of your own progress towards a proof for these kind of questions. Where have you arrived in your attempts?

Comment: @Kenji I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show us your attempts.

Comment: Just give me 10 mins I'll upload my attempt.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{cyc}\sin^2\alpha=\sum_{cyc}\frac{\tan^2\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}\tan^2\alpha(1+\tan^2\beta)(1+\tan^2\gamma)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(1+\tan^2\alpha)}=$$
$$=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(\tan^2\alpha\tan^2\beta\tan^2\gamma+2\tan^2\alpha\tan^2\beta+\tan^2\alpha)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(1+\tan^2\alpha)}=$$
$$=\frac{\tan^2\alpha\tan^2\beta\tan^2\gamma+1+\sum\limits_{cyc}(\tan^2\alpha\tan^2\beta+\tan^2\alpha)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(1+\tan^2\alpha)}=1.$$

Comment: Thanks for answering.. But I'm in 12th grade, I have not seen this type of solving method, if you have time and know any simpler method, I will be a great help.. Again Thanks bro

Comment: @Kenji I think my solution is very easy and smooth. I am ready to explain. Which step is not clear?

Comment: I didn't understand why you used the subscript "cyc" in summation sign and Multiplication sign. This is the first I saw this method of solving question.. I am used to summation goes from 1 to n.

Comment: @Kenji it's a designation   only for to write less. For example, $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sin^2\alpha=\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\beta+\sin^2\gamma$ or $\prod\limits_{cyc}(1+\tan^2\alpha)=(1+\tan^2\alpha)(1+\tan^2\beta)(1+\tan^2\gamma).$ It's nothing!

Comment: Thanks ..now I got it .

Comment: @Kenji You are welcome!

Comment: Nice solution....